# Rails test database is not been rollbacked after each tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am debugging a rails 5 application. It is supposed to use transactional fixtures.

```
#test_helper.rb
self.use_transactional_tests = true
```

But I am tracing the tests and finding that some updates to the database on one test, causing another test to fail because it's not rolling back.

What could be the cause of not rolling back database after each test?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using RSpec:

The documentation on [Transactions](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/1357926b331136ee635281db52e10b22f2de6081/features/Transactions.md) explains the circumstances under which actions are not performed in a transaction:

> **Data created in `before(:context)` are not rolled back**

> `before(:context)` hooks are invoked before the transaction is opened.

That means that any objects created in `before(:context)` (which is an alias for `before(:all)`) will be persisted to the database. Patterns like this are sometimes used because it means fewer database writes and possibly improved performance:

```rb
describe Foo do
  before(:context) do
    @foo = subject.save
  end

  # ...
end
```

But the problem is every run of the test will persist a new record to the database. Switch these over to `before(:example)` (or `before(:each)`) to have them run in a transaction. As noted in the docs:

> **Data created in `before(:example)` are rolled back**

> Any data you create in a `before(:example)` hook will be rolled back at the end of the example.

```rb
describe Foo do
  before(:example) do
    @foo = subject.save
  end

  # ...
end
```

This will run the save to the database for every example but they'll each be run in a transaction that will be rolled back and no records will be persisted to the database.